# Angular Testing Subscription.unsubscribe() using JEST

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-test

I am trying to test the ngOnDestroy method using jest.spyon and I'm getting an error while running the test.

My component looks like this.

```
import {component, on Destroy, onInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
...


export class ProductPageComponent {

 dataSubscription: Subscription;

 ngOnDestroy(){
  this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();

 }

}
```

I tried following the similar test case with Angular Jasmine and my test in Jest look like this:

```
it('should unsubscribe when ngOnDestroy is called',  () => {
 component.dataSubscription = new Subscription();

 jest.spyOn(component.dataSubscription, 'unsubscribe');
 component.ngOnDestroy();

 expect(component.dataSubscription.unSubscribe()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); 
});
```

But I am getting this error: Is there different way to spy Subscription using Jest?

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Comment: You are not using spyOn correctly, please refer to docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object

Comment: Thanks so much @opel. Finally I realized what I did wrong :)